# R - Can't access data frame column using same of column in a second data frame

Tags: r, string

Suppose I have the following two data frames:

```
a <- data.frame(1:4, c("one", "two", "three", "four"))
b <- data.frame(1:4, c(4, 6, 7, 9), 4:7, c(9, 10, 44, 45))

names(b) <- c("one", "two", "three", "four")
names(a) <- c("number", "group")
```

Given

```
a$"group"
# "one" "two" "three" "four"
b$"two"
# 4 6 7 9
```

why cant I access b$"two" like so?

```
b$(a$"group"[2])
# NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the order of the factor levels (`a$group` is a factor), I would transform `a$group` into a character vector

`a$group <- as.character(a$group)`

Then following works:

```
b[, a$group[2]]
b[[a$group[2]]]
b[[a[["group"]][2]]]
```

So, the trick is to index columns via parantheses `[]`